# Is there any function that would allow me to register custom stylesheets for the Customizer itself?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'd want for my Customizer to use a custom skin, or, well, enhancements as one would call it.

Unfortunately, `WP_Customize_Control` doesn't do the job, nor can I find anything about it.

What would be the docs / resources to start building this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're after getting custom CSS ontop of Wordpress's Admins Customizer buttons, inputs, and controls - you can do something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->base == 'customize') {
        wp_register_style( 
            'custom_wp_admin_css', 
            plugins_url( 'your-file.css', __FILE__ ),
            //get_template_directory_uri().'your-file.css',
            false, 
            filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/your-file.css' )
            // get_template_directory() . '/your-file.css' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
    }
});
```

The commented out lines are incase your making a theme, not a plugin.

In `your-file.css`, you can then do your custom CSS

```
#customize-controls * {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do I have to use `!important` on each declaration? Isn't there a way to make my file of higher-order?

Comment: Actually you should just enqueue at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action. No need then to check for the current screen.